# The program does not work. It started but with errors and did not read two xml file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The program does not work. It started but with errors and did not read two xml file?

C: \program> powershell.exe -noexit .\1.ps1 chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml
Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 20 character: 42+ $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object {$ ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 21 character: 49+ $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $ Path2) | ForEach-Obj ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentComman

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    function chpecent {
    param(
      [string]$Path1,
      [string]$Path2
    )
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $textnamef1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $textnamef2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $textPercent = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
        $inputpecentw1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $inputpecentw2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $Read = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
        $Save = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
        $form1_Load = {
     $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
            $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path2) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
        }    
        $Read_Click = {
            #press read button
          $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
            $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path2) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
             }
        $Save_Click = {
            #press save button
             $new_value1 = $inputpecentw1.Text
             $new_value2 = $inputpecentw2.Text
            [xml](Get-Content $Path1)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $new_value1) }; $_.Save($Path1) }
            [xml](Get-Content $Path2)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $new_value2) }; $_.Save($Path2) }
          } 
         $form1.Controls.Add($textnamef1)
         $form1.Controls.Add($textnamef2)
        $form1.Controls.Add($inputpecentw1)
        $form1.Controls.Add($inputpecentw2)
            $form1.Controls.Add($Read)
        $form1.Controls.Add($Save)
        $form1.ClientSize = '800, 800'
        $form1.Text = 'проценты'
        $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
        $textnamef1.AutoSize = $True
        $textnamef1.Location = '80, 40'
        $textnamef1.Text = 'MIK_Autokontinent.xml'    
        $textnamef2.AutoSize = $True
        $textnamef2.Location = '80, 80'
        $textnamef2.Text = 'MIK_AutoPremium.xml'    
        $textPercent.AutoSize = $True
        $textPercent.Location = '20, 10'
        $textPercent.Text = 'Percent'
        $inputpecentw1.Location = '20, 40'
        $inputpecentw1.Size = '20, 20'

        $inputpecentw2.Location = '20, 80'
        $inputpecentw2.Size = '20, 20'
        $Read.Location = '20,740'
        $Read.Size = '100, 40'
        $Read.Text = 'Прочитать'
        $Read.add_Click($Read_Click)
        $Save.Location = '680,740'
        $Save.Size = '100, 40'
        $Save.Text = 'Сохранить'
        $Save.add_Click($Save_Click)
      return $form1.ShowDialog()
    } #End Function
    chpecent | Out-Null
```

**Example of file MIK_Autokontinent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1"/><FieldCostOptions Enabled="1" Version="1"><IncreaseCost Enabled="1" Percent="-5"/></FieldCostOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `param` block to the top of your function, declaring the two paths:

```bsh
function chpecent {
param(
  [string]$Path1,
  [string]$Path2
)
...
}
```

and then replace all hardcoded paths with those:

```bsh
    $form1_Load = {
        $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
        $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path2) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
    }
```

... and so on, and then finally call the function like:

```
PS C:\> chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml
```

Comment: @danrather you need to dot-source (or "import") the function first. `. .\path\to\script.ps1; chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml`

Comment: Please read the actual error messages. `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: @danrather no, at the very top of your script

Comment: @danrather read your error messages :) [Try this](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/854075899d8533fcdfe8d8d0ad9244bf)

Comment: how do i run this program?